# Calling 3 partial views of 3 different models and different controller actions results in an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have parent view as follows

```
parent view
@{
project.Models.CustomerRegistration CustReg = ViewBag.CustReg;
project.Models.ForgetPassModel ForgotPassword = ViewBag.ForgotPassword;
project.Models.LoginModel Login = ViewBag.Login;
project.Models.LocalPasswordModel localpassword = ViewBag.localpassword;

}


 @Html.Partial("Registration", CustReg, ViewData)
 @Html.Partial("_Login", Login)
@Html.Partial("_ForgotPassword", ForgotPassword, ViewData)
```

register parial

```
using (Html.BeginForm("RegistrationCustomer", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{

  @*@Html.ValidationSummary()*@
   <div>
       <h3>First Name</h3>

       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-    control" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
       @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ReferalId)
            <h3>EmailId</h3>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
      <h3>Password</h3>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-3"/>
}
```

login partial

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegistrationCustomer", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
           <h3>Email ID</h3>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
      <h3>Password</h3>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn-3"/>
 if (Request["returnUrl"] == "Guest Login Failed")
 { 
<label>Incorrect UserId or Password</label>
}  
}
```

forgotpassword partial

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{
<h2>@ViewBag.Role</h2>
<p>Please enter your UserName to get the login details</p>
<h3>Email Id</h3>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
  <div class="buttons-set">
 <input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn-3"/>
}
```

mycontrollers

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl,string role)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();


        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ViewBag.Role = role;
        Session[SessionKeys.PreviousPage] = Convert.ToString(Request.UrlReferrer);

        if (returnUrl == "Guest Login Failed")
        {
   ModelState.AddModelError("UserName1", "The user name provided is    incorrect.");
            return PartialView();
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel log, string returnUrl, string role)
    {
        string Url = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();//Session[SessionKeys.PreviousPage].ToString();
        ////string Url = "www.RekoMart.com";


        string a = log.UserName;
        log.URL = Url;
        LoginModel Login = ul.ValidateLogin(log);
        if (Login != null)
        {
            if (Login.LoginType.ToLower() == "customer")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login.userId, true);//cust.RememberMe);
                Session[SessionKeys.CurrentCustomer] = Login;
                Session[SessionKeys.CurrentUSerId] = Login.GUESTID;
                Session[SessionKeys.URL] = Url;
                Session[SessionKeys.CUSTOMERUSERID] = a;
                Session[SessionKeys.LoginTypeID] = Login.LoginTypeID;
                Session[SessionKeys.UserId] = a;
                Session[SessionKeys.ISCUSTOMER] = "True";
                Session[SessionKeys.status] = "True";
                Session[SessionKeys.UserRole] = "customer";
                Session[SessionKeys.CUSTOMERID] = Login.CUSTOMERID;

                //int cartProductsCount = 0;
                //if (Session[SessionKeys.cartProductsCount] != null)
                //{
                //    cartProductsCount = Convert.ToInt16(Session[SessionKeys.cartProductsCount].ToString());
                //}
                //if (Session[SessionKeys.PreviousPage] != null)
                //    return Redirect(Session[SessionKeys.PreviousPage].ToString());
                //else
                //    if (cartProductsCount > 0)
                //        return RedirectToAction("Purchasecart", "Customer");
                //    else
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else 
            {
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.Role = role;
                // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                ModelState.AddModelError("", " provided is incorrect.");
                //return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl = "Guest Login Failed", role = "Customer" });
                return RedirectToAction("RegistrationCustomer", new { returnUrl = "Guest Login Failed", role = "Customer" });

            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.Role = role;
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", " provided is incorrect.");
            return PartialView(log);
        }
        }

public ActionResult Registration(int ReferalId)
      {
          CustomerRegistration cr = new CustomerRegistration();
          cr.ReferalId = ReferalId;

          return PartialView(cr);
      }


    [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Registration(CustomerRegistration model)
      {
          model.ReferalId = 0;
          ICollection<ModelState> er = ModelState.Values;
          int x = er.Where(a => a.Errors.Count > 0).Count();
        int id=0;


          UserAccountService uas = new UserAccountService();
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
              // Attempt to register the user
              try
              {
                  model.SponcerId = "0";
                  CustomerRegistration cust = uas.RegisterCustomer(model);


                  if (cust != null)
                  {
                      model.Message = "Successful";
                      Response.Write("Successful");
                      return PartialView(model);

                  }
                  else
                  {
             ModelState.AddModelError("RegistrationCustomer", "Registration Failed");
                      model.Message = "Registration Failed";
                      return PartialView(model);
                  }

              }
              catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
              {
                  ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
              }

          }
          else
          {
              return RedirectToAction("RegistrationCustomer", model);

          }
        return PartialView(model);  
      }
```

I get this error on clicking submit on blank registration form. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'project.Models.CustomerRegistration', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'project.Models.LoginModel'.

Comment: Check the edit on my answer.

Comment: You should forget this and create a ViewModel, which has 4 properties (for CustomerRegistration, ForgetPassModel, etc), pass that to the main view and then use `@Html.Partial("Registration", Model.Registration)`

Comment: Edited my answer again because of the controller code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

That error appears when a model you're trying to bind to a strongly typed partial view is null. When rendering this partial view inside a page, if you pass a null model to the `@Html.Partial(...)` method, the renderer defaults to sending the current page's model instead.

Your problem is that in this action (which I'm assuming corresponds to your parent view above) you do this:

```
public ActionResult Registration(int ReferalId)
{
    CustomerRegistration cr = new CustomerRegistration();
    cr.ReferalId = ReferalId;

    return PartialView(cr);
}
```

But in your view you do this:

```
@{
    project.Models.CustomerRegistration CustReg = ViewBag.CustReg;
    project.Models.ForgetPassModel ForgotPassword = ViewBag.ForgotPassword;
    project.Models.LoginModel Login = ViewBag.Login;
    project.Models.LocalPasswordModel localpassword = ViewBag.localpassword;
}
```

The ViewBag is not some magical empty object generator. It's a dictionary where you can store data that doesn't necessarily have anything to do with your model for the duration of one request. The main problem you have besides not populating the ViewBag in the first place is that you're rendering all your views with `return PartialView(...)`. This rendering method ignores anything you might set in your ViewBag completely. So, to solve your issue we need to make a few small modifications, assuming the models for your Login and ForgotPassword partials are supposed to be empty.

```
@{
    // delete the custReg, let the partial inherit the model from the parent
    project.Models.ForgetPassModel ForgotPassword = new project.Models.ForgetPassModel();
    project.Models.LoginModel Login = new project.Models.LoginModel();
    project.Models.LocalPasswordModel localpassword = new project.Models.LocalPasswordModel();

}


@Html.Partial("Registration")
@Html.Partial("_Login", Login)
@Html.Partial("_ForgotPassword", ForgotPassword)
```

Comment: i know its null but i have not idea about why its null.

Comment: @KiranWaghmare can you edit your question and show me the code in the controller where you populate all those `ViewBag.` variables?

Comment: i have not added ViewBag.Login.

Comment: @KiranWaghmare That's your problem. You're trying to render a view using a model that doesn't exist. If you just want to render the view with empty fields, put `ViewBag.Login = new project.Models.LoginModel();` in your controller action and you're good to go.

Comment: Ok, the Error is gone, but not showing my validations for fields.

Comment: @KiranWaghmare Could you be a bit more specific? What are you doing and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: now when i click any of the buttons of the partial views, the page redirects to the other folders in the view folders to view error msgs for example if I click submit of the _register parital view instead of redirecting to partial view the controller sends it to Views/Account Folder to search register view instead of _Register in Views/Shared same with _Forgotpassword and __Login. Do u have any idea why it happens? the code same as above.

Comment: This is a different problem altogether and it should be posted in a new question, along with your project structure. I'd be more than happy to have a look at that and help you. Also, if I've fixed your error, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: @Kiran: may I add my own request that you accept this answer? Thanks.